# Kotlin: как реализовать валидацию через интерфейсы?

Tags: kotlin

Вот, допустим, у меня есть DTO:

```
open class ContactDto: AbstractDto() {

    open var phone: String? = null
    open var email: String? = null
    open var user: Long? = null
}
```

Мне нужно обязательно сделать поле phone обязательным при создании сущности и необновляемым. То есть, для одних случаев `@Null`, для других - `@NonNull`. В Java проблема решается интерфейсами, например:

```
interface Validate {

    interface Create {}
    interface Update {}
}
```

с последующей маркировкой поля нужным интерфейсом, например, в Java это бы выглядело так:

```
public interface Validate2 {

    interface Create {}
    interface Update {}
}
```

и вешаем на поле (и на контроллер тоже потом):

```
@NotNull(groups = {Validation.Create.class})
@Null(groups = Validation.Update.class)
public String phone;
```

В Котлине же меня, как обычно, ждали сюрпризы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как создавать классы-маркеры для валидации и как их вешать на поля? Буду признателен, если сразу с примером, как это делается в контроллере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @field:NotNull(groups = [Validate2.Create::class])
    @field:Null(groups = [Validate2.Update::class])
    open var phone: String? = null
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже осилил. Там, кстати, можно без field, а напрямую Null.